# How to use Protocol Buffer as a serialization and deserialization for data integration using NIFI

Tags: protocol-buffers, apache-nifi

I'm new to Apache NiFi. My requirement is to migrate data from oracle to postgres.
So far, I was using ExecuteSql processors to extract data (i.e., in Avro Format) and Loading data to postgres using PutDataBaseRecord (Config. with AvroReader).
Now, I would like to use Google's Protocol Buffer instead of Avro.
I have gone through the documentation of Protocol Buffers but, My bad I'm very poor at understanding the documentation. And I'm confused that how can I achieve my requirement? I can understand that need to write custom processors, but Not able to write down a pseudo code or steps. Can anyone help me out in understanding it better and drafting the pseudocode or steps.

Comment: Make your tasks smaller until you find exact issue/blocker. 1st - exclude nifi. Then it will sound like: how to convert jdbc ResultSet to protobuf in java language. What I want to say - your question is too broad to help you.

Comment: Okay Thank You :)